# How to convert Point coordinates into CSV format?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, point, geometry, csv

The [GDAL documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html) describes how to convert a ShapeFile into CSV data. The *layer create options* (`-lco` parameter) allows to prepend the coordinates of Point features to the actual attributes values.

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv input.shp -lco GEOMETRY=AS_XY
```

Note that I omitted the Z-dimension for my example here.
For some reason this results in the following error message:

```
FAILED: Layer input already exists, and -append not specified.
        Consider using -append, or -overwrite.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer input (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

I am using GDAL 1.10.0.

**Questions:**

- How can I get this running?
- Is there an option to omit the feature attributes: I only want to export the latitude and longitude values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Layer input already exists" error is due to an existing file "output.csv", presumably from a previous attempt. This file needs to be deleted to make a new file (the `-overwrite` option sometimes works, but not always). From POSIX shells, use `rm output.csv`, or from a Windows shell, use `del output.csv`

To only show `X,Y` fields, provide an empty select field list to ogr2ogr by using: `-select ""`

Comment: There was no file named `output.csv`. The check seems to be buggy since the error did not disappear **until I removed all `.csv` files** in the folder. The `-select` option works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error depicts that system don't have permissions to overwrite/append the output csv file because you have not mentioned it in your gdal ogr2ogr command.

Possible solution can be addition of these Params in your command

```
Ogr2ogr -f 'CSV' output.csv input.shp -lco GEOMETRY=AS_XY -append
```

I hope it will help.